# ASP FileUpload: Field has been reset by validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, file-upload

I'm having a problem using FileUpload and the validation of a TextBox.

1. I choose a valid file from my hard disk and type an invalid text into the text box.
2. I click on a submit button, the server validation of the text box returns a failure and displays me the defined error message (the invalid text is still in the box).

Unfortunately "someone" clears the choosen path from the file upload form. Why? And how can I prevent that?

Comment: Are you doing this inside of an UpDate Panel..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Both are in the same Panel, but not an UpdatePanel

Answer (score 0):

For security purposes, browsers like chrome or ff or ... do not give you the physical path of input file, so for example if you get value of a fileupload in chrome it will return 'c:/fakepath/myfile.txt' and with postback because in request and response there is no info of real path of file on your file system, browser clears it and you should choose file again and again.

Answer (score 0):

here is what you could add to your page
here is a link as well that explains how to use and why [File Upload not working with update panel](http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.com/2009/02/file-upload-not-working-with-update.html)

```
Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

Here is another possible work around as well

Place your fileuploader and submit button in another update panel and add a post back trigger for this update panel.

If you want to use AsyncFileUpload here is an example as well
[AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx)